# Centred jQuery accordion (with its width calculated with jQuery) displays weird behaviours!

Tags: jquery

All Images are 320px.

The width of their container (a anchor tag) is set to `78px` by default.

When you hover one anchor tag it is expanded to `310px`.

I wanted to center them so I did: `margin: 0 auto` to `#accordion ul`.

In order to center it, I couldn't give a fixed width to `#accordion ul`. So I dynamically calculated its width with jQuery.

But when you hover an anchor tag the total width changes (one image will expand to 310px).
So I have to do `310-78px` (not sure if my math is right).

It works but

1. When I hover the last image I get some weird behaviour.
2. `#accordion ul` is not centred until you hover it (should be centred by default).

You can check it here: http://alexchen.info/brianfunshine/

Any suggestions?

js:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
    /**
     * jQuery Accordion
     */
    $j('#accordion ul li a').hover(function() {
        // if the element is currently being animated (to a easeOut)...
        if ($j(this).is(':animated')) {
            $j(this).stop().animate({width: "310px"}, {duration: 450, easing:"easeOutQuad"});
        } else {
        // ease in quickly
            $j(this).stop().animate({width: "310px"}, {duration: 400, easing:"easeOutQuad"});
        }
        }, function () {
        // on hovering out, ease the element out
        if ($j(this).is(':animated')) {
            $j(this).stop().animate({width: "78px"}, {duration: 400, easing:"easeInOutQuad"})
        } else {
        // ease out slowly
        $j(this).stop('animated:').animate({width: "78px"}, {duration: 450, easing:"easeInOutQuad"});
        }
    });
    /**
     *  Calculate the size of all the images inside the Jquery Accordion
     */
    var customWidth = $j('#accordion ul li a').outerWidth(true);
    var customNumber = $j('#accordion ul li a').size();
    // add extra 78px if it is hovered
    $j('#accordion ul li a').hover(function () {
        $j('#accordion ul').css('width', (customWidth*customNumber+242) + 'px');
      }, function () {
        var cssObj = {
          'width' : customWidth*customNumber,
        }
        $j('#accordion ul').css(cssObj);
    });
});
```

html:

```
    <div id="accordion">
        <ul>
            <?php // Create and run custom loop
                $custom_posts = new WP_Query();
                $custom_posts->query('post_type=page_content&page_sections=Slider (Front Page)');
                while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post();
            ?>
            <li class="landscapes"><?php the_content(); ?><></li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'll take a crack at it in a moment here, but just to be certain, you did in fact intend to generate a "People" tab twice, correct?

Comment: By the way, I don't know if you found the hover animation binding somewhere and adapted it, or created it yourself, but all the same I really enjoyed it! Quite clever. :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took a tiny bit of finessing due to an IE7 bug with floated, relatively positioned elements (which I wanted to use so your anchor tags fill the entire list item), but I wanted to give you a backwards compatible solution.

The concept here is to wrap your <ul /> in an overflow: hidden container that is centered with auto left/right margins and let it handle clipping the menu list:

1. Expand the unordered list's width to
   allow plenty wiggle room for the
   elements to slide without dropping
   below the list block. It won't
   matter because its parent container
   will hide any overflow.

   ```
   div.menu
   {
       width: 700px;
       height: 200px;
       margin: 0 auto;
       overflow: hidden;
   }

   ul
   {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       height: 200px;
       width: 1400px;
       display: block;
       list-style: none;
       overflow: hidden;
   }
   ```
2. Unbind your hover function from your
   last list item by using a .not()
   selector. We never really need to
   resize this item because its
   overflow is clipped. Best we don't
   attempt to animate it at all.

   ```
   $j('ul > li').not(".people2").hover(function(){...});
   ```
3. Add a relatively positioned
   container inside each list item and
   nest the anchor within, setting its
   position to absolute, width to 100%
   (which will keep it at block width),
   and height to fixed menu size. This
   will cause your anchor to span the
   full width and height of the list
   item at all times.

   CSS

   ```
   ul > li > div
   {
       position: relative;
   }

   ul > li > div > a
   {
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
       height: 200px;
   }
   ```

   HTML

   ```
   <li class="people">
       <div>
           <a href="#people"></a>
       </div>
   </li>
   ```

See an example at [this jsfiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/lthibodeaux/U33Cr/)

I think the elegance of this solution is that it will eliminate any need for jQuery calculations and instead relies completely on CSS to produce your desired effect. Hope this is helpful!

Comment: I added the white line separators between images back in to the example's CSS. Not sure if you intended those or not. You can just remove the div.outerStripe container and background color, positioning, and repeat on the list item CSS if it's unwanted. [See this fiddle for the markup](http://jsfiddle.net/lthibodeaux/U33Cr/7/)